# Files status in Git Bash terminal in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how to get this nice status bar in git in vs code

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Posh-Git** It’s a PowerShell environment for Git. It’s an open source project hosted on GitHub. https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git

For more information on how to install it and more. https://sechannel.com/2019/06/30/git-with-posh-git-simplifying-setup/

Comment: Thanks!! Excellent!